# Java Web Start and License Management

Tags: java, java-web-start

Can Java Web Start integrate into some licensing management mechanism so that it will only grab the update if that specific user is licensed for upgrades at that time?

So, let's say a user purchases the software, downloads and runs it. They are authorized for 1 year of upgrades. Java Web Start automatically looks for updates when you start the application, right? Is there a way for it to maintain user credentials during that check so that after 1 year it no longer allows them to get the new version?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to do it with a custom URL locked to some local license file, but I guess it could be easily shared. On the server you can have a main controller that looks at the URL, looks up the support level and lists new jars or not depending on the validity of the user/ her license.

---

Another way is to use the user name + authentication to first identify the user and her license and then the app updates it self by downloading jars and have another class that is launched, that asks the main app to exit, copies the jars and then restarts main app.

So one of the jars would be the updater, that is called by the main app on start (if default short cut), then the updater would update jars and then call the main app with -no-update flag.